# How can I track where my mouse goes and then if it goes beyond 400 pixels then print "you lose"?

Tags: processing, mouse

When my mouse goes beyond 400 pixels, it needs to print "you lose".

I have already tried the code below. Nothing happens

```java
void setup() {
   size(800, 600);
   if (mouseX > 400) {
     print("game over");
   }
}
```

Nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

The `setup()` function only runs **once**, right when the program first starts up.

If you want your code to continue running, consider putting it inside the `draw()` function, which runs 60 times per second.

```
void setup() {
   size(800, 600);
}

void draw() {
   if (mouseX > 400) {
     print("game over");
   }
}
```